# How can i shorten this new object code?

Tags: c#, object, enums

I know it is a silly question and it is probably easy but i'm staring screen like 3 hours and i still can't seem to figure out. Any idea how to shorten this code? I have `public enum Type` and `public enum Size` in my class Car.cs.

```
        Car car1 = new Car((CarType)0, (Size)0);
        Car car2 = new Car((CarType)0, (Size)1);
        Car car3 = new Car((CarType)0, (Size)2);
        Car car4 = new Car((CarType)1, (Size)0);
        Car car5 = new Car((CarType)1, (Size)1);
        Car car6 = new Car((CarType)1, (Size)2);
        Car car7 = new Car((CarType)2, (Size)0);
        Car car8 = new Car((CarType)2, (Size)1);
        Car car9 = new Car((CarType)2, (Size)2);
```

Edit: I print them with a method like this

```
        Group1Print(car1, car2, car3);
        Group2Print(car4, car5, car6);
        Group3Print(car7, car8, car9);
```

Comment: Create an array, make a loop, divide, modulo

Comment: What about two nested loops.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen You can stop at your second step.

Comment: Why two loops when you can do it in one.

Comment: Don't have an enum named `Type`. This conflicts with the built-in `System.Type`. Consider explicitly making it `CarType` (or `Make`, or `Model`, or `Brand`, depending on what it really is) or making these "types" subclasses of `Car`.

Comment: What does the edit to your question have to do with this? You should probably consider taking an array or an IEnumerable as the input as sets are typically variable length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        var cars = new List<Car>();
        foreach (Type type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Type)))
        {
            foreach (Size size in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Size)))
            {
                cars.Add(new Car() {Size = size, Type = type});
            }
        }
```

Or LINQ version:

```
var cars = (from Type type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Type))
            from Size size in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Size))
            select new Car() {Size = size, Type = type}).ToList();
```

Comment: Your first version was way better, now you've made it unreadable

Comment: will change it back then

Answer (score -1):

```
var cars = Enumerable.Range(0, 9)
                     .Select(i => new Car((Type)(i / 3), (Size)(i % 3)))
                     .ToArray();
```

Comment: (As a note, this only works because the enums are square)

Comment: Now all you have to do is never add members to the enums again! Otherwise, good luck figuring out how to change the loop.

Comment: As long as they are square or one set is a multiple of the other a single look will be pretty easy.  Though any pattern could be followed and an you oculs just shorten the set if some other multiple is needed.  (I guess this could be difficult for some but hopefully the majority of devs are good with maths.)

Comment: Developers that are smart enough to understand what this does in C# would have no need for asking the original question. More damningly, however, this code is trivial to break by simply forgetting to change it as members are added, since there's no clear indication that this is necessary. `9` and `3` have become magic constants. This is simple, short and wrong.

Comment: What happens when the enum values change and you have more than 3?  What happens when the two enums have different counts of values?  Why is there magic numbers in your code (3)?

Comment: @MatthewWhited Or you could just write the *simpler* code that doesn't require you to have to do all of that additional work every time you want to read the code and figure out what it does, see if it's correct, change it because one of the underlying enums change, or deal with the fact that it now *can't* work because of such a change.  It's way more work in exchange for...way more work.  It's just all around worse in every way.  Just because you *can* figure out some deliberately obtuse and less effective code doesn't mean you should have to.

Comment: @Servy and what if there are more types in his Enum that are used in other scenarios but he only wants the 3 in this case? His answer is perfectly valid for what was posted. How do you know that is the functionality he wants? What if there are 50 `Size` options but only 3 are for his car? Now you're making assumptions. Matthew's answer is doing exactly what OP asked. Pretty sure there is a big SO post about not making assumptions about what OP wants...

Comment: Seeing at the guy was hard coding values versus using the enum value I really don't see the issue.  Other than to be annoying (which gives me makes me enjoy leaving this answer right here :)

Comment: @Dispersia Good question indeed.  This code doesn't properly convey either semantics.  I, as a reader of the code, have no idea if the goal is to cover all of the enum values, or just the first three, or even if `0`, `1`, or `2` are expected to be valid enum values.  If the goal is to convey one of those other options, there are lots of ways of writing code that does that, and this isn't one of them.  *This answer* is the one making tons of assumptions about the specifics of the situation, for it to even be valid, which is one of its biggest problems.

Comment: @Servy, I would have thought you would have been around long enough to understand integer math.

Comment: @MatthewWhited The math is not the problem.  Figuring out *what* your code does is easy. Figuring out why it does it, or what it's supposed to do, are both hard, because your code doesn't represent the semantics of what the code is supposed to do, and instead is focused on a mechanism that is completely unrelated with the actual semantics of the business requirements.  It's the same problem that the OP's own solution has; it's not hard to figure out *what* it's doing, but it's hard to figure out what it's *supposed* to do, and if it's actually doing what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: That's enough. Everyone's made their point, and this exchange is becoming unconstructive. It can end here. If you want to discuss it further, take it to chat.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried something like this. Seems like a valid answer. Thanks for help.

```
public List<Car> CarList = new List<Car>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                CarList.Add(new Car((CarType)i, (CarSize)j));
            }
        }

        Group1Print(CarList[0], CarList[1], CarList[2]);
        Group2Print(CarList[3], CarList[4], CarList[5]);
        Group3Print(CarList[6], CarList[7], CarList[8]);
    }
```

Comment: You should only answer your own question if no one else had.  You have two answers here, one that is almost identical to your provided answer.  You should mark one of them correct if they helped you at all.

Comment: Thanks for the excitation. I just wanted to to show what helped me incase someone might look for the same answer. I marked right answer helped me.